# Input button - resize text but keep button size

Tags: html, css

I want to make a custom button CSS and try to make "pressed" button looks like it's pressed:

```css
input[type="button"]
{
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: .2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em #777;
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


input[type="button"]:active
{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .1em #777;
  font-size: .9em;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra ligula vitae eros ultrices luctus. 
<input type="button" value="Button one"> Vivamus ut felis massa. Cras a urna egestas, vehicula diam eu, accumsan lectus. Sed feugiat, odio quis cursus venenatis, felis dolor ultricies arcu, sit amet convallis eros nisi vel neque. <input type="button" value="Second button"> Cras facilisis in diam vel eleifend. Duis at tincidunt dui. Aliquam egestas at metus in malesuada. Nulla tincidunt lorem vel cursus porttitor. Phasellus gravida eleifend nulla.
```

Looks ok for me, but changing font size expectedly resizes button itself, causing the whole layout to change. At the other hand, I cannot set button' width because I want to make a 'generic' CSS for all my pages and all buttons there, and I do not know what text will be inside.
The question: is there a way to keep button's width while changing its font size? Or the only way is to use "div in div" instead of buttons?

Comment: You can experiment with setting the 'padding' on the button, when 'active'.

Comment: Sure, I tried to change padding/margin, but have no idea how to calculate it for arbitrary text

Comment: You can use a relative padding, in percent.

Comment: Not sure if I understood. What is the difference? Could you pls show me an example?

Comment: A relative padding is a percent of the Width, meaning it will be larger on big texts.

Comment: Yes, but how could it help in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the font-size on active, you can reduce the scale of the button so it still maintains its original width but also reduce in size visually.

```
transform: scale(0.95);
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't knew that transform keeps original size! Thank you, shame on me -  I had the same idea but was too lazy to check because was pretty sure it will resize whole button

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with setting the relative `'padding-left'` and '`padding-right`' on the button, when `'active'`.

Here I set it to 10% (which is obviously too big):

```css
input[type="button"]
{
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: .2em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em #777;
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}


input[type="button"]:active
{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 .1em #777;
  font-size: .9em;
  height: 2rem;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
 }
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed viverra ligula vitae eros ultrices luctus. 
<input type="button" value="Button one"> Vivamus ut felis massa. Cras a urna egestas, vehicula diam eu, accumsan lectus. Sed feugiat, odio quis cursus venenatis, felis dolor ultricies arcu, sit amet convallis eros nisi vel neque. <input type="button" value="Second button"> Cras facilisis in diam vel eleifend. Duis at tincidunt dui. Aliquam egestas at metus in malesuada. Nulla tincidunt lorem vel cursus porttitor. Phasellus gravida eleifend nulla.
```

Comment: I suppose it’s not possible to achieve that with “padding”. For example let there be the text with 100px width that becomes 90px for “active” that gives 10% difference. But for another text it could be 200px/190px width and 5% difference. I don’t see the way to calculate, and I’m afraid it’s not possible